# Cannot access Koha

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I'm following [this guide](http://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_on_ubuntu_-_packages) to run Koha on Ubuntu.

My file contents are shown below.

/etc/koha/koha-sites.conf:

```
DOMAIN=".eit-Dimension-5100"  # Change this to be your domain.
INTRAPORT="80"  # TCP listening port for the administration interface
INTRAPREFIX=""
INTRASUFFIX="-intra"
DEFAULTSQL=""
OPACPORT="80"  # TCP listening port for the users' interface
OPACPREFIX=""
OPACSUFFIX=""
ZEBRA_MARC_FORMAT="marc21"  # Possible values are 'marc21', 'normarc' and 'unimarc'
ZEBRA_LANGUAGE="en"  # Possible values are 'en', 'fr' and 'nb'
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 library.eit-Dimension-5100
127.0.0.1 library-intra.eit-Dimension-5100

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

After running this command:

```
sudo xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'yazgfs/config/pass' /etc/koha/sites/library/koha-conf.xml
```

...I still get the same Apache default first page on navigating to:

```
lynx http://library-intra.eit-Dimension-5100:80
```

Can any one tell what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are suggested to restart your koha server and browse the site without port (:80)